# Is there a way for me to programmatically get if the side menu is floating or fixed?

Tags: buildfire

I am developing a plugin on Buildfire platform. I see that an app can have either floating or fixed side menu. I would like to change the position of my plugin content depending on the side menu style.
I already checked [appearance](https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/How-to-use-Appearance) and there is nothing that can help me. Am I missing something?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I dont believe this is provided currently (as of Feb 2020). The closet method would be `buildfire.appearance.getAppTheme` which only returns fonts and colors

```
{
  "appName": "AlicanDemo2019",
  "colors": {
    "backgroundColor": "#18191a",
    "titleBar": "#09a3ee",
    "titleBarTextAndIcons": "#ffffff",
    "headerText": "#09a3ee",
    "bodyText": "#ffffff",
    "icons": "#09a3ee",
    "primaryTheme": "#09a3ee",
    "successTheme": "#14cb5d",
    "infoTheme": "#69d5ff",
    "warningTheme": "#faba41",
    "dangerTheme": "#ed4b4b",
    "defaultTheme": "#0677ae",
    "footerMenuBackgroundColor": "#18191a",
    "footerMenuIconColor": "#09a3ee"
  },
  "fontId": "Architects+Daughter",
  "fontName": "Architects Daughter"
}
```